# WPF Element Rendering Order

Tags: c#, wpf

**Background**

I needed a charting system for an app that I am working on and was unable to find anything free that was able to do what I required, so I decided to write my own.

**The solution so far**

I'll avoid going into to much detail of the design at his point but this is an example of the XAML code and a screen shot of the result. Hopefully this will give some indication of how the system (a set of custom WPF controls) is structured.

```
<Window x:Class="ChartTestApp_1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:charts="clr-namespace:BB.Play.Wpf.Charts;assembly=BB.Play.Wpf.Charts"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="560"
        Background="Black">

  <Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/BB.PLay.Wpf.Charts;component/Themes/Generic.xaml"/>
  </Window.Resources>

  <Grid>
    <charts:Chart Margin="20" BorderThickness="0">
      <charts:Chart.Axes>
        <!-- The Y axis -->
        <charts:NumericAxis Style="{StaticResource VerticalNumercAxis}"
                            Name="ValueAxis"
                            IsScrollable="True"
                            IsZoomable="True"
                            Minimum="{Binding MinValue}"
                            Maximum="{Binding MaxValue}"
                            Source="Value">
          <charts:Axis.Hatching>
            <charts:LinearHatching Style="{StaticResource MajorVerticalHatching}" IsAuto="True" MinimumSpacing="30"/>
            <charts:LinearHatching Style="{StaticResource MinorVerticalHatching}" IsAuto="True" MinimumSpacing="30"  IsGridLine="True"/>
          </charts:Axis.Hatching>
        </charts:NumericAxis>

        <!-- The X axis -->
        <charts:TimeAxis Style="{StaticResource HorizontalTimeAxis}"
                         Name="TimeAxis"
                         IsPrimaryAxis="True"
                         Minimum="{Binding StartTime}"
                         Maximum="{Binding EndTime}"
                         Source="Time">
          <charts:Axis.Hatching >
            <charts:LinearHatching Style="{StaticResource MinorHorizontalHatching}" IsAuto="True" MinimumSpacing="240" LabelFormat="|dd MMM yy"/>
            <charts:LinearHatching Style="{StaticResource MinorHorizontalHatching}" IsAuto="True" MinimumSpacing="60" LabelFormat=""/>
            <charts:LinearHatching Style="{StaticResource MinorHorizontalHatching}" IsAuto="True" MinimumSpacing="20" IsLabeled="False" IsGridLine="True"/>
          </charts:Axis.Hatching>
        </charts:TimeAxis>
      </charts:Chart.Axes>

      <!-- The main chart area -->
      <charts:Chart.Presenters>

        <!-- The background -->
        <charts:UIPresenter>
          <Grid>
            <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
              <Rectangle.Fill>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
                  <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0.0" />
                  <GradientStop Color="#000044" Offset="1.0" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
              </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <TextBlock Foreground="SteelBlue" FontSize="14" Margin="5">Chart Test 1</TextBlock>
          </Grid>
        </charts:UIPresenter>

        <!-- The grid lines -->
        <charts:GridLinePresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>

        <!-- The data -->
        <charts:DataPresenter DataItemsProvider="{Binding DataProvider}"
                              charts:ChartPanel.HorizontalPosition="Center"
                              charts:ChartPanel.VerticalPosition="Center"
                              XAxisName="TimeAxis"
                              YAxisName ="ValueAxis"
                              ClipToBounds="True">
          <charts:DataPresenter.ArtistTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <charts:Artist X="{Binding Time}"
                             Y="{Binding Value}">
                <charts:Artist.Template>
                  <DataTemplate>
                    <Ellipse Height="5" Width="5" Fill="DarkOrange"/>
                  </DataTemplate>
                </charts:Artist.Template>
              </charts:Artist>
            </DataTemplate>
          </charts:DataPresenter.ArtistTemplate>
        </charts:DataPresenter>
      </charts:Chart.Presenters>
    </charts:Chart>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image]

**Current situation**

I am currently working on the part of the system that provides the grid lines for the chart. This functionality is provided by a control called *GridLinePresenter* and is included in the *Presenters* at the bottom of the XAML.
Since the chart can be both scrollable and zoomable I could not use static grid lines and since the grid lines align with the hatch marks on the axis it seemed logical to use their position to arrange the grid lines.

**Some code**

One of the following methods is called whenever the axis either scrolled or zoomed.

```
private void UpdateScrollPosition(Point currentScrollPosition)
{
  var distance = Orientation == PartOrientation.Horizontal
    ? _lastScrollPosition.X - currentScrollPosition.X
    : _lastScrollPosition.Y - currentScrollPosition.Y;
  _lastScrollPosition = currentScrollPosition;
  VisualRange.Move(distance);
  InvalidateAxis();
  RaiseAxisChanged();
}

private void Zoom(double delta)
{
  VisualRange.Zoom(delta / 12.0);
  ScaleRange(DesiredSize);
  InvalidateAxis();
  RaiseAxisChanged();
}
```

The last line in both methods is

```
RaiseAxisChanged();
```

This fires an event (not routed) that the Presenters can subscribe to so that they can update themselves according to the new axis details. In the above example this includes the GridLinePresenter and the DataPresenter but not the UIPresenter since it does not need to change. In both cases where it is used the event handler is simply

```
private void OnAxisMoved(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  InvalidateMeasure();
}
```

**The problem**

Since the hatching for the axis is calculated in the *MeasureOverride* of the *AxisHatching* control it is essential that the Axis and all it's sub-controls are processed before the measure pass of the rendering calls the *MeasureOverride* on the *GridLinePresenter* otherwise it will end up using the old values for the hatching positions to arrange the grid lines.

As it stands even though the *Axis* is invalidated before the *GridLinePresenter* and exist higher up in the visual tree this does not guarantee that it will be processed first. Actually the order at the moment is

*GridLinePresenter.MeasureOverride()*

*Axis.MeasureOverride()*

*Axis.ArrangeOverride()*

*GridLinePresenter.ArrangeOverride()*

Which is resulting in the wrong number of grid lines being drawn (when zooming) or being drawn in the wrong position.

**The question**

First - How does WPF determine the order to process elements during rendering? I assumed this would be either their position in the visual tree and/or their Z-Index but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Second - Can this be influenced

Comment: Without reading through your code I think that calculating tick mark positions in any MeasureOverride is wrong. It should instead be done in the ArrangeOverride methods, where the final dimensions are ultimately known.

Comment: Yeah I agree but that will take a bit of re-work and I'm pressed for time so that can wait for now. It definitely avoid the issue of having to store the position for later use in the ArrangeOverride.

Comment: Even cleaner would probably be to just react on the SizeChanged event.

Comment: That's not a bad idea, I might look into it. At the moment though because the ticks are calculated and added/removed as Children as needed I have to do this in the MeasureOverrided because the size of the tick and the text dictate the overall size of the axis. This wouldn't be an issue if I had a fixed width/height for the axis but I didn't want to go that way.